# How can I fix AMP Stylesheet error in my blogger site?

Tags: css, blogger, amp-html

I am using Blogger for my following website:

http://ssc.bdresult.info/

After integrating AMP I tested my website and got few AMP errors.

**Invalid CSS stylesheet**

`The attribute 'href' in tag 'link rel=stylesheet for fonts' is set to the invalid value 'https://www.blogger.com/dyn-css/authorization.css?targetBlogID=2053857296326564086&zx=0affe301-5faf-4dbf-bc73-928ca14db607'.`

Answer (score 1):

You can use only whitelisted font:

> Font providers can be whitelisted if they support CSS-only
>   integrations and serve over HTTPS. The following origins are currently
>   allowed for font serving via link tags:
>
> Typography.com: **cloud.typography.com** Fonts.com:
>   **fast.fonts.net** Google Fonts: **fonts.googleapis.com** Font
>   Awesome: **maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com**

[AMP Specification](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/spec#custom-fonts)